# How to get tables from database first approach without .tt and edmx files?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am working on database first approach. I followed the following link

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620

I'm able to get the cs files. But cs file are coming under edmx folder. but I want to get cs file directly as similar as code first approach

I am using entity framework 6 and mvc 5

This is my screen shot

[image]

Comment: Those CS files actually arent in a folder. Visual Studio is just grouping the related files together and you can disable this behavior with a setting in VS. If this is not what you are asking, please clarify your question. Why do you want only the CS files? The EDMX and TT files make it easy to regenerate if you change the databse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get "Code First from database" install the latest Entity Framework Tools for Visual Studio 2012/2013 (version 6.1.3)